# Crash on accessing NSManagedObject property after migratePersistentStore: to another URL on OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, osx-mavericks, core-data-migration

I have a code that works fine on OS X 10.9 before I migrate the persistent store to another URL. After migration app crashes when I try to execute fetch request and sort by an existing property of fetched items. On OS X 10.8 it works fine before and after migration. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here's the store migration, nothing fancy:

```
    BOOL success = [storeCoordinator migratePersistentStore:store toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath] options:nil withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
```

Migration proceeds successfully, without errors.
Here's the crashing code (which worked fine before migration):

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == nil", @"parent"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // SORTING BY "sortOrder" PROPERTY CRASHES THE APP
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]; 
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error; 
    NSMutableArray *fetchResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Crash details:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x60)

0x00007fff89a64ad0 in _propertyAtIndexForEntityDescription ()
0x00007fff89a631dd in snapshot_get_value_as_object ()
0x00007fff931ea49f in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] ()
0x00007fff931e904c in _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors ()
0x00007fff931e8e69 in -[NSArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] ()
0x00007fff89a459f0 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
```

**Update [2]**
Thanks to Tom Harrington's question, I was able to narrow the issue down to this:

**Update [3]**
It appears there's a number of specific keys causing this crash. Out of dozen of different properties of the fetched items, accessing 3 particular properties of type *NSDate* and *'double'* cause the app to crash. All of them has some meaningful value.

There're other properties of type *NSString, Boolean, Integer 16, Integer 32* and *Binary Data*. Some of them are nil, some set to default value, some has some other value. They can be accessed without any error. **AND** there's one *NSDate* property without any value including default and it can be accessed without problems also.

**Why does it crash?** Before migrating store to another URL I can successfully access these properties.

Comment: That's the complete crashing code? I only ask because the stack trace seems to suggest a problem with sorting, but your sample code doesn't use any sort descriptors.

Comment: @TomHarrington I actually set sort descriptors, I omitted them because didn't think it was relevant. See updated code please.

Comment: @TomHarrington, yes, thanks to your eagle eye, the problem is in sortOrder key. When I try to access it in any way after migration even as simple as [item valueForKey:@"sortOrder"] app crashes. Can't yet understand why.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything you need to do with the migrated store to make that work. Unfortunately I don't have any other suggestions at the moment.

Comment: @TomHarrington thank you. I was able to dig further, seems there's a specific set of properties causing app to crash after migration when I try to access them. Non-nil NSDate and double value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with a specific project created a while ago. Probably during these years something got messed in project files and settings.

Comment: What did you do to get the project right? Trashed it? I have a similar problem right now.